# SpringBoot REST Json Request to Protobuf

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, protocol-buffers

I am trying to convert a json REST request to protobuf format.

Sample JSON input:

```
{
    "id": 111,
    "name": "Anirban"
}
```

REST controller:

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public @ResponseBody Student handleStudent(@Valid @RequestBody Student student){
    System.out.println("Name:" + student.getName());
    System.out.println("ID:" + event.getId());
    // A service to convert student to protobuf and send to other service
    return student;
}
```

Proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package student;
option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.student.protobuf";
option java_outer_classname = "StudentOuter";

message Student {
    int32 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}
```

Here I want to convert the received Student json request to protobuf object and send to another service. Couldn't find any proper guide for it. Any help?

Comment: Are you trying to generate that proto file? If so, you could use a templating engine like freemarker or velocity. Probably overkill for this very small usecase but would definitely make sense if the proto file gets more complex.

Comment: The protobuf object looks very simple, so you could do this with by string concatenation for a small usecase. Otherwise you need an protobuf object with its own serializer.

Answer (score 0):

You use https://gitlab.com/protobuf-tools/proto_domain_converter to convert between the Student class received from REST to the Student class generated by protobuf